# How to access client application from web application with service application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I would like to write a Web Application that can interact with 3D Cad program for our company. So I was thinking that I would create a program that would be locally installed on the client machines which would send and receive data back and forth from Client App to Web App. I would like to use xml for moving the data back and forth too. Does anyone suggestions or can this even be done?

Comment: That's a web service. See [tag:WCF].

Comment: Sounds like a typical web service use case. Try to learn more about WCF

Comment: So a web service can do what i'm looking for? In other words it gets installed on the client machine? This is new for me.

Comment: no - a webservice gets installed on a server and gets used from a client... if you install an app (WinForms/WPF/Console/Windows Service) on the client you can host in that app a webservice...

Comment: @Yahia ok, I think I get what your saying. I've programmed only for WinForms and ASP.Net. So WCF is kind of gray. I am trying to find some good examples/videos/tutorials currently.

Comment: Here is a link [WCF](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2010/12/15/create-and-consume-wcf-service-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx), but it does say that ASMX is another alternative and easier to program.

Comment: but ASMX is harder to host in your client app - so if you want to go the ASMX route then the webservice will be on the server-side

Comment: one Question still remaining: **What do you want to do with service?** can you describe better about relation app and service, service effect on app?

Comment: I want the [Service App] to processes macros and/or send rec'v data to the [Clients Application]. It should send results back to the [Web Application] via [WCF] and so on...

Comment: ASMX should no longer be used. Microsoft considers it to be a "legacy technology".

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need `2 way communication` between app and service. and for solving that there are two way:

1. use *`two service`* and they must be client of each other (Hard way)
2. use *`Duplex Services`*. (you can use [WCF-Duplex](http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,b891610a-6b78-4b54-b9a6-4ec81c82b7c0.aspx) [services](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCF_Duplex_UI_Threads.aspx) - it's not simple)

in this case you must handle too many issue's.(take look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165858/is-wcf-duplex-a-good-choice))

> As example:
>   app need to notify self on your service and service save address of active client's. so every time service want's to call one of client, service must find client's address in active-client's and then call that.

Let me know if this help you.